# Using Karabiner Elements, how can I toggle the WASD keys to arrow keys. Only while Caps lock active?

Tags: element, karabiner

Love this program and thankful for any help

Like the title states, I have my left hand on my SHIFT KEY, OPTION KEY and COMMAND key all the time. but I hate when I have to use my arrow keys to move shapes. I would like the ability to change WASD as arrow keys to nudge shapes around. This also allows for the pinky to hit the left SHIFT KEY so that I could move shape 10px at a time. However, I want to be able to toggle to the arrow function by pressing Caps lock and holding it until I release. Doing this will enable me to make more use of hotkeys while building/UI.

To summarize:

1. Program active
2. keyboard is in default state when Caps lock is off
3. While Caps lock is on I am able to use WASD as arrow keys
4. Once I hit Caps lock, keys will return to default state.

Thank you so much for whatever help you guys can throw my way. Hope this has already been addressed and is easy fix

Comment: (Just an observation: on most keyboards caps_lock is a "toggle key" whose state is often indicated by an LED. So "pressing & letting-go" normally won't work – actually "pressing, typing-what-you-want, pressing again" is more comfortable, once you are used to it.)

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
{
    "description": "WASD arrow Keys toggled by Capslock",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                    "type": "variable_unless",
                    "value": 1
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "caps_lock",
                "modifiers": {
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "set_variable": {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                    "type": "variable_if",
                    "value": 1
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "caps_lock",
                "modifiers": {
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "set_variable": {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "value":  0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                    "type": "variable_if",
                    "value": 1
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "a",
                "modifiers": {
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "left_arrow"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                    "type": "variable_if",
                    "value": 1
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "s",
                "modifiers": {
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                    "type": "variable_if",
                    "value": 1
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "w",
                "modifiers": {
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                    "type": "variable_if",
                    "value": 1
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "d",
                "modifiers": {
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "right_arrow"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can either place the code inside the brackets of the `"rules": []` element of the file `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`, or create a new JSON file in `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications`, wrapping the code above in:

```
{
  "title": "WASD arrow Keys toggled by Capslock",
  "rules": [
    (insert code here)
  ]
}
```

If you opt for the separate JSON file, once saved you can enable it through the Karabiner-Elements UI via Complex Modifications > Add rule.

I‘m using Karabiner beta 12.1.56 but it should work on Karabiner stable.

Note that this script replaces the functionality of caps lock, meaning: it works as an arrow key toggler, not as an uppercase key toggler.

This is a modification of the script "TouchCursor Mode" from the [Karabiner site](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/), which toggles a variable when pressing capslock, then uses WASD as keys or arrows depending on that variable. Similar technique to the one used by @user9680958.

Comment: The problem I'm having with this is that ijkl arrow keys is TOGGLED on/off when I press AND release caps. This means holding caps doesn't always put me in this mode. https://gist.github.com/henrebotha/666bb23d5259e6c298145cb006b02202 This link contains a script that enables the mode only while caps is held down, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

**Both solutions for caps lock mode and caps hold mode:**

- p.s. you can easily switch the script down below to "wasd" or "hjkl", etc.

**1. Setup Karabiner:**

- Download Karabiner
- When opening it requires to enable some stuff in the Settings (just follow the steps it requests from you)

**Set up the Script:**

2. Create a JSON file on your desktop:

   - cmd + space to open the spotlight
   - type in terminal
   - type in cd
   - type in cd desktop
   - touch myscript.json
   - copy paste one of the codes down below in the new file
3. Go back to the terminal

   - Type in cd
   - Type cd desktop
   - Type mv myscript.json ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications
4. Now open Karabiner Elements and go to "Complex modifications"

   - Press "add Rule"
   - Now there should be your custom rule to enable
   - Have fun.

**Code 1 for Caps lock "to enter arrow key mode" and press again "to exit arrow key mode":**

```
{
  "title": "ijkl arrow Keys toggled by Capslock",
  "rules": [
    {
        "description": "ijkl arrow Keys toggled by Capslock",
        "manipulators": [
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_unless",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "caps_lock",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "set_variable": {
                            "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            },
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_if",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "caps_lock",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "set_variable": {
                            "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                            "value":  0
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            },
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_if",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "j",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "left_arrow"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            },
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_if",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "k",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "down_arrow"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            },
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_if",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "i",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            },
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_if",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "l",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "right_arrow"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code 2 If you want to hold Caps while using the arrow Keys use this one instead:**

```
{
  "title": "ijkl arrow Keys toggled by Capslock",
  "rules": [
    {
        "description": "ijkl arrow Keys toggled by Capslock",
        "manipulators": [
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_unless",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "caps_lock",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "set_variable": {
                            "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            },
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_if",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "caps_lock",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "set_variable": {
                            "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                            "value":  0
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            },
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_if",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "j",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "left_arrow"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            },
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_if",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "k",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "down_arrow"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            },
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_if",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "i",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            },
            {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "name": "wasd_arrow_keys_mode",
                        "type": "variable_if",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "l",
                    "modifiers": {
                        "optional": [
                            "any"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "key_code": "right_arrow"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Code 1 and 2 are identical. Sadly, I want to have your option 2. Can you pls help to update your answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
{
                    "type": "basic",
                    "description": "",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "w",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "up_arrow"
                
                        }
                    ],
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "type": "variable_if",
                            "name": "caps_lock pressed",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
{
                    "type": "basic",
                    "description": "",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "s",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "down_arrow"
                
                        }
                    ],
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "type": "variable_if",
                            "name": "caps_lock pressed",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
{
                    "type": "basic",
                    "description": "",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "a",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "left_arrow"
                
                        }
                    ],
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "type": "variable_if",
                            "name": "caps_lock pressed",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
{
                    "type": "basic",
                    "description": "",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "d",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "right_arrow"
                
                        }
                    ],
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "type": "variable_if",
                            "name": "caps_lock pressed",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
               {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "caps_lock",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "caps_lock"
                        },
                    
                        {
                            "set_variable": {
                                "name": "caps_lock pressed",
                                "value": 0
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "type": "variable_if",
                            "name": "caps_lock pressed",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                
                },

                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "caps_lock",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },

                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "caps_lock"
                        }
                    ],
                    "to_if_alone": [
                        {
                            "set_variable": {
                                "name": "caps_lock pressed",
                                "value": 1
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This rule will set up a remap so that holding Caps + J/K/L/I will function as arrow keys. This configuration is effective while you're **holding down Caps Lock** and pressing the corresponding arrow keys. Remember, once you're done navigating, you'll need to press Caps Lock again to deactivate it

**Note**: If you are using an external keyboard, make sure to enable it in the device section of the app. By default, these changes are only applied to the built-in keyboard.
Also, you need to quite and restart the app for the changes to be applied.

```json
{
    "description": "Change caps_lock+jkli to arrow keys",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "l",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "caps_lock"
                    ],
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "right_arrow"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "j",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "caps_lock"
                    ],
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "left_arrow"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "k",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "caps_lock"
                    ],
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "i",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "caps_lock"
                    ],
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```